# image from a file in android

Tags: android, file-upload

i am using the following code to get a bitmap from a imagefile.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( requestPackage.getPics().get(i), options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,60,baos)
```

but it returns a file not found exception even though the file exists.
this is the image path used `"file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/form_message_1.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove 'file:' from that path and try again.